# How to write Redirect Rule in .htaccess to upload files with POST and GET data?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

In my application I have written simple redirect rule in .htaccess like

```
RewriteRule ^controllers/([^/]+).php/addCatlogFile/([^/]+) http://www.notjustresearch.com/controllers/$1.php?action=addCatlogFile&responce=$2 [NC,P]
```

I want to upload file with POST and GET data, but file more that 10KB can not upload.
If it is more than 10KB then " Large data in post " error has been displaying.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini of the `notjustresearch.com` server, try increasing the max post size:

```
post_max_size 10M
```

or whatever size you want it to be. You should also be able to do it using htaccess:

```
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

but it has to be on the `notjustresearch.com` server, not the server that the rewrite rule is on.

Comment: Your suggestion will work indeed but Can't we write Redirection Rule which won't convert file data in POST and propagate as it is?

Comment: @user3228848 you cannot affect request bodies using redirects or rewrites, so any POST data, or lack thereof, cannot be affected